# Possible to set width of src image of an iFrame?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to display big images within an iFrame. The images are loaded dynamically on various button clicks. While this works fine, because the images are huge, I need to resize it on the fly when it is displayed within the iFrame.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks for any help.

This is what I am doing.

```
<iframe id="myFrame" style="width:950; height: 600px; border: 0px solid red;" src="myImage1.png"></iframe>
```

I need to set a width on myImage.png.

Comment: resize what? the image or the iframe?

Comment: The image, not the iFrame. I am already setting a fixed height and width on the iFrame. The reason for doing this is, I am developing a mobile website and the images need to be able to be pinch-zoomed. This is the easiest solutuin I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Have the button apply CSS classes to the images and use CSS to set the dimensions of the image.

Answer (score 0):

load the image in iframe like bellow to achieve resize image,

```
function loadImage(index){
  img.src = images[index];
  var content = "<html><body><img src='"+images[index]+"' width='300' height='200'></body></html>";
  iF.contentWindow.document.open('text/html', 'replace');
  iF.contentWindow.document.write(content);
  iF.contentWindow.document.close();
}
```

Check he working [sample](http://tinkerbin.com/tRPSvN20) I tried with iframe and img.